# Including .pm files in perl script

Tags: perl

I have some .pm files stored in a dynamic path.  For example:

```
/home/scripts/project_pm_files
```

Now I have a perl script which must include all these .pm files.

Please tell me a way to include these files given that the location of these files is dynamic meaning there is no fixed path of these .pm files.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `$PERL5LIB` environment variable to the correct path on each system.

Answer (score 1):

add `use lib /home/scripts/project_pm_files;` to your script. And then you can use `use xxx.pm` to include the modules.

Comment: But the path /home/scripts/.. is not fixed , how to include in such a way that it just tries to find the directory project_pm_files and include those in the script ?

Comment: What means `is not fix? Can you add an example?

Comment: Suppose in one of my system the directory is located in /home/scripts/..  , In another system I have the same directory in /home/new/scripts , but I dont want to hardcode the use lib command for each every system , I wanted to be taken care of by a single command

Comment: use can add both path with `use lib` or you can use `require` to import the module.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lib` pragma, passing path to pm files to it. Note that you have to do it in `BEGIN` block, so that it is evaluated during script compilation. That's because `use` statements are evaluated during compilation.

```
my $path;
BEGIN { $path = find_project_pm_files(); }
use lib $path;

use my_module_1;
...
use my_module_n;
```

If your pm files are always relative to main script, you can use [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/lib/FindBin.pm) module:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";
```